# Why doesn't a SIP server require authorization for this INVITE?

Tags: sip

I am using [Telephone](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/telephone/id406825478) softphone on macOS. When making a call, it sends the following INVITE request:

```
INVITE sip:login@sip.antisip.com SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.13:63980;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPj1J2vaemfz28guXCjwsCNuCM4K7AGksTF
Max-Forwards: 70
From: "Andriy Makukha" <sip:nickname@sip.linphone.org>;tag=CK3y0yotv2v1AclTF2sBahkYcA721X7t
To: <sip:login@sip.antisip.com>
Contact: "Andriy Makukha" <sip:nickname@192.168.1.13:63980;ob>
Call-ID: Tu2FDGIveVVM1BZFKY1IUYFxkxuBWZU5
CSeq: 18057 INVITE
Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
Supported: replaces, 100rel, norefersub
User-Agent: Telephone 1.4
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length:   541

...
```

As you can see, the request doesn't have neither `Proxy-Authorization` nor `Authorization` header. However, the server never challenges this request with a `407 Proxy Authentication Required` response. The call always goes through directly.

On the other hand, when I use another SIP client, the server always sends Proxy Authentication Required response.

What does Telephone do that allows it to avoid authentication while making a call?

**Additional information:**

- after launch, the softphone sends a REGISTER request and receives a `401 Unathorized` response and then resends the REGISTER with the `Authorization` header
- the REGISTER request is sent to 91.121.209.194, which is the A-record for the domain sip.linphone.org (domain of the caller)
- however, the INVITE request is being *sent directly* to 91.121.30.149 which is the A-record for the domain sip.antisip.com (domain of the callee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the headers in the incoming INVITE:

```
From: "Andriy Makukha" <sip:nickname@sip.linphone.org>;tag=...
To: <sip:login@sip.antisip.com>
```

In theory, the above INVITE should be:

- sent to sip.linphone.org first
- **challenged with a 407 by sip.linphone.org**
- sent to sip.linphone.org with credential
- forwarded from sip.linphone.org to sip.antisip.com
- **NOT challenged by sip.antisip.com**

Reading your description of your issue, it is possible that you have misconfigured your application and your SIP identity (in From header) is wrong? If [Telephone](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/telephone/id406825478) is configured to send directly to sip.antisip.com then, the call will be forwarded by sip.antisip.com without 407.

As the owner of sip.antisip.com, I could (should?) reject incoming call to my users if they appear to not come from the service of the From header. But I have not implemented such anti-spam policy. I would love to add some restrictions in my policy to prevent unwanted configuration, but my users will complain... Even if they are wrong!

Some reading:

- [rfc5039](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5039) - The Session Initiation Protocol (SIP) and Spam
- [rfc8197](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8197) - A SIP Response Code for Unwanted Calls

Comment: I did not configure Telephone beyond adding the Linphone account. But you are right: Telephone sends the INVITE request directly to Antisip, which is rather strange. And From header was correct.